# Update session array variable in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am suck with an issue.

I have a session array which i need to update. Don't know how to update it.

```
$detailsData    =   $this->session->userdata['detailsData']['tot_amt'];
```

I need to update the value of 'tot_amt'.How to implement this?

Waiting for response.....

Comment: show you full session arrray

Comment: what is your session variable ?

Answer (score 4):

If  '**detailsData**'  is the session variable and has an array in it. Then

```
$detailsData    =   $this->session->userdata('detailsData');
$detailsData['tot_amt']= "Any Value";
$this->session->set_userdata('detailsData', $detailsData);
```

Comment: It's bad if you're using it with any event driven or async function and you're checking and updating session in more than one places. It will cause error.

Answer (score 1):

For update session value like this :

```
// modify session
$this->session->set_userdata('tot_amt', 'New value');
```

when you need to replace old data just `unset` previous data and then set again your new data

Example :

```
$session_data = array('uid' => 'test user', 'logged_in' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

//remove old data
$this->session->unset_userdata($session_data);

// modify session
$session_data = array('uid' => 'New user', 'logged_in' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```